# Cant use navigate on UseEffect React Native for Splash Screen

Tags: android, react-native, use-effect

Hello guys so I'm trying to make Splash Screen with Stack Navigator. So I Have 3 Main Files App.js , Home.js, and SplashScreenJs. I want my Splashscreen to move into Home after 5 seconds but I can't afford to make it. I was able to use console log with the UseEffect but not with the navigate. It shows error " ReferenceError: Can't find variable: navigation"

App.js Code:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          header: () => null
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen 
          name='Splash Screen' 
          component={SplashScreen}
        /> 
        
        <Stack.Screen 
          name='Home' 
          component={Home}
        /> 
      </Stack.Navigator> 
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

SplashScreen.js

```
const SplashScreen = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
      navigation.navigate('Home')
    }, 5000);
  });
  
  return (
      <LinearGradient colors={['#53CDE2','rgba(83, 205, 226, 0.43)','rgba(83, 205, 226, 0.25)']} style={styles.SplashWrapper}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/logo.png')}/>
          <Text style={styles.SplashSlogan}>Well Organized, Better Day</Text> 
      </LinearGradient>
  )
}
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the navigation prop like below

```
const SplashScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    }, 5000);
  },[]);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, It didn't show any error, but my Splash screen didn't move to the Home.js, any reason why ?

Comment: even after 5 seconds ?

Comment: yeah it stay at the splash screen, i even try changing it into 1 second

Comment: Let me make a snack and check this

Comment: @KimSan sorry its navigation.navigate fixed the answer now

Comment: the home still didn't show, is it possible that the home screen already rendered but it's hidden behind the splash screen ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233775/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-kim-san).

Comment: I finally found the reasons why and its such a clumsy one. Basically I import the home but from ./components/SplashScreen. That's why it still showing the splashscreen content.

Comment: is there any other props other then navigation.navigate ? because the user was able to move back to splash screen and then stuck.

Comment: this is the way to navigate but if you want to remove the splash screen from the stack check the authentication flow https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow